# sorting a file of records error

Tags: delphi, record, pascal, bubble-sort

I need to sort a file of records but I am not quite sure of how to do it.  I have a file of records and I have attempted to sort them using a simple bubble sort but I am stuck and need some help. Could anyone help me? I will list the code below.

```
HighScoreFile = file of HighScoreRecord;


var
frmEnterDetails: TfrmEnterDetails;
HighScoreMasterFile: HighScoreFile;
HighScore:HighScoreRecord;
FileArray:array[1..20] of HighScoreRecord;
i:integer;

Procedure Sort
var
  i,j,temp:integer;

AssignFile(HighScoreMasterFile, 'HighScores.dat');
Reset(HighScoreMasterFile);
while not eof(HighScoreMasterFile) do
begin    
  i:=i+1;
  read(HighScoreMasterFile, HighScore);
  FileArray[i].Name:=HighScore.Name;
  FileArray[i].Date:=HighScore.Date;
  FileArray[i].FinalScore:=HighScore.FinalScore;

  for i:=0 19 do
    for j:=0 to 18 do
      if FileArray[j].Score > FileArray[j+1].Score then
        begin
          FileArray[temp]:=FileArray[j];
          FileArray[j]:=FileArray[j+1];
          FileArray[j+1]:=FileArray[temp];
       end;
end;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Your Sort procedure is incomplete. `i` is not initialized. Indexing `FileArray` should start with 1 in your for loop. `temp` is never initialized. `i` is never used in the for loop. etc.

Comment: Also you make the sort during the read of the file. Read the entire file, and after that make the sort.

Comment: Please do not close this thread as I can only test it in school which will be tomorrow

Comment: There are a few minor details which can be improved: (1) you can read directly from HighScoreMasterFile into FileArray[i], without the HighScore variable. (2) You can use 'i' instead of 'temp' in the sorting part.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that is not correct 100%, I haven't test in the IDE. You can use the debugger in order to see how this algorithm is working step by step. Also this link explain you very well how the bubble sort is working http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Bubble_sort.

```
    HighScoreFile = file of HighScoreRecord;


    var
    frmEnterDetails: TfrmEnterDetails;
    HighScoreMasterFile: HighScoreFile;
    HighScore:HighScoreRecord;
    FileArray:array[1..20] of HighScoreRecord;
    i:integer;

    Procedure Sort
    var
      i,j,temp:integer;
    begin
    AssignFile(HighScoreMasterFile, 'HighScores.dat');
    Reset(HighScoreMasterFile);
    i := 0;
    while not eof(HighScoreMasterFile) do
    begin    
      i:=i+1;
      read(HighScoreMasterFile, HighScore);
      FileArray[i].Name:=HighScore.Name;
      FileArray[i].Date:=HighScore.Date;
      FileArray[i].FinalScore:=HighScore.FinalScore;
    end;

      for i:=1 to 19 do
        for j:=1 to 18 do
          if FileArray[i].Score > FileArray[j+1].Score then
            begin
              temp := i;
              HighScore := FileArray[temp];
              FileArray[temp]:=FileArray[j];
              FileArray[j]:=HighScore;
           end;
  end;
```

Comment: to display the array using a label, would I use something like this? lblScore1.Caption:=FileArray[1].HighSore.FinalScore